# How do I retrieve a particular piece of metadata of a selected List Item in Visual Studio (Sharepoint)?

Tags: sharepoint-2010, properties, metadata, hashtable, splistitem

I'm doing up a web part using visual studio for my sharepoint site and I require part of it to retrieve documents which are related to the selected one.

Each document which I've created on the sharepoint site for testing purposes has its own metadata and I wish to retrieve the documents which have a particular piece of metadata (say, 'file name' or 'written by' etc.)

hence in the method which I've coded for this particular function, I've managed to *retrieve the metadata collectively into a hashtable* (or so I think i have) but I can't seem to extract a **single piece** of metadata out of it.

```
protected void displayFileNames(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    String selectedDocLib = TypeOfDocument.SelectedValue;
    objCurrentWeb = SPContext.Current.Web;
    SPListCollection objDocLibList =     objCurrentWeb.GetListsOfType(SPBaseType.DocumentLibrary);

    String tempStr = "";
    SPList tempDocLib;
    Hashtable hT = new Hashtable();

    foreach (SPList docLibList in objDocLibList) {
        tempStr = docLibList.Title;
        if (tempStr.Equals(selectedDocLib)) {

            tempDocLib = objDocLibList.TryGetList(selectedDocLib);

            foreach (SPListItem objTempDocLibItem in tempDocLib.Items) {
                hT = objTempDocLibItem.Properties;
                int isOriginal = hT.GetHashCode();

                ListBox1.Items.Add(objTempDocLibItem.Name);

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Please help me out here!!

Thank you!!!

Hailey